# How to specify the duration of subscription in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am implementing stripe subscriptions and I can't find anywhere in the api documentation how to specify the duration of the subscription when creating a checkout session. This is what I have so far:

```js
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      description: "My First Test Customer (created for API docs)",
      email: "some.email@gmail.com",
      address: {
        city: 'Toronto',
        country: 'CA',
        line1: "Some Address",
        line2: "Some unit number",
        postal_code: "M5G0V1",
        state: "ON",
      },
      name: "Some Name",
      phone: "Some Number",
    }); 
    const price = await stripe.prices.create({
      unit_amount: 599,
      currency: 'cad',
      recurring: {interval: 'month', interval_count: '1'},
      product: 'prod_KZfHFK4nfCqlGS',
    });
    const subscriptionSchedule = await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.create({
      customer: customer.id,
      start_date: 'now',
      end_behavior: 'cancel',
      phases: [
        {
          items: [
            {
              price: price.id,
              quantity: 1,
            },
          ],
          iterations: 24,
        },
      ],
    });
    console.log(subscriptionSchedule);
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      success_url: 'http://localhost:8080/stripeSessionSuccessHook',
      cancel_url: 'http://localhost:8080/stripeSessionCancelHook',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      customer: customer.id,
      line_items: [
        {price: price.id, quantity: 1},
      ],
      mode: 'subscription',
    });
```

I am trying to create a subscription that the customer pays monthly for 24 months. I am using Subscription Schedule suggested in the answers, and indeed such subscription with 24 months is being created. However, when creating a new checkout, and in case the payment is successful, it will create a Subscription that spans for 12 months... In the end, I have 2 subscriptions. One created by Subscription Schedule (24 months, desired one), and other Subscription (12 months). Is there a way I can somehow pass this subscription schedule to checkout, so 2 subscriptions don't get created.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Subscription would typically auto-renew after every billing cycle if it is paid for. The [recurring.interval](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-recurring-interval) is set in the Price and the max recurring interval is a year. **[Note : As of Jan 2024, Stripe now supports a maximum of three years interval]**

If you want to end the subscription after 2 years, you would use Subscription Schedules : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules.

For your use case, with a Price that has `recurring.interval=year`, you would create a Subscription Schedule that has a single Phase with `iterations=2` and `end_behavior=cancel`.

You can refer to this example : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#installment-plans

Note that Subscription Schedules does not currently work with Checkout or the Customer Portal. If you want to use Checkout, a workaround is :

1. The customer pays for the subscription via Checkout
2. Create a Subscription Schedule for the existing (and already paid for) subscription : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription
3. Update the newly created Subscription Schedule parameters to end the subscription after 2 years : https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/update

You should not depend on the success redirect to perform any important actions on the client.  On the client, the customer could close the browser window or quit the app before the redirection occurs. You would want to setup a webhook to listen for the `checkout.session.completed` event and create the Subscription Schedule upon receipt of this event.

You can read more about setting up webhooks here :

- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders
- https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I updated my code, and described the issue. Would really appreciate if you know how to avoid duplicate subscription creation .

Comment: updated to answer your question

Comment: Thanks Alex! I think this sounds legit. I was thinking of doing this way, but the only thing I was having wrong(in my head) was that, after the customer pays, the redirect was going to backend endpoint where I manipulate the subscription (adding to subscription schedule) and then redirect to some page. But the web-hook sounds better. If I get it to work, I will post my solution.

Comment: wanted to pop back here to mention that after creating the subscription schedule from an existing schedule, you're going to need a separate API call to update the relevant parameters to end the subscription after 2 years : https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/update

Comment: Thank you Alex, finally got it working! Had to re-read what you suggested here multiple times.